# Set style of Control in C++ code behind

Tags: c++, styles, winrt-xaml

I want to change an implicit style in the codebehind in C++, but the documentation doesn't give me any clear direction.

Basically, I want to do this (how it would be done in C#).

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Style style = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Style { TargetType = typeof(FlipViewItem) };
    style.Setters.Add(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter(FlipViewItem.IsTabStopProperty, false));
    this.Resources.Add(style.TargetType, style);
 }
```

But in C++. This makes sure that FlipViewItems aren't tab-stops by default.

Cheers,
Tomas

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
auto comicFont= ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::FontFamily("Comic Sans MS");
auto comicFontStyle = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Style(TextBlock::typeid);
auto fSetter=ref new Setter(TextBlock::FontFamilyProperty, comicFont );
comicFontStyle->Setters->Append(fSetter);       
this->Resources->Insert(comicFontStyle->TargetType,comicFontStyle );
```